# Using a bug-fixed Apache component with Flex 4.6?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

*I think I know the answer to this but thought I would put out the question, since I'm not a Flex "super user" in any sense.*

**Situation:** I've inherited a large legacy enterprise project done in Flex 4.6. For some small feature additions I needed to use the mx `PopUpMenuButton`. After some development time I started seeing a reproducible bug. Didn't see any reporting of it on the web until I found this Apache Flex bug report:[abnormal focus behavior in popup ultimiately causes unhandled exception](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flex-issues/201404.mbox/%3CJIRA.12687964.1389223361633.81760.1396989860169@arcas%3E) which accurately describes it and states that it has been fixed.

**Question:** I can't update to Apache Flex 4.12+ – my project is too large and there would be just too much testing required. Is there any way I can use the `PopUpMenuButton` from 4.12+ as a custom component, bringing in whatever dependencies there are with it?

My guess is: no – that the dependencies are too extensive for this to be practical and would need too much refactoring to avoid namespace collision. Thoughts? Or alternatives to the `PopUpMenuButton`?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097576/398606). I worked on a project a long time ago where we monkey patched Adobe AIR classes in order to convert the project to a web based application.

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall much about it anymore, it was in 2011 ;)